# package "dart_to_js_script_rewriter" is not a dependency

Tags: dart, auth0

I just started learning dart.

first I created an angular2-dart based project from https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/quickstart.html and it worked properly.

now I want to add auth0-lock dart package from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/auth0_lock, so I modified pubspec.yaml to the following:

```
name: go_dart_angular2_zingchart
description: Go Dart Angular2 with ZingChart Started Kit
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: ^2.0.0-beta.18
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  auth0_lock: ^0.1.0
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: client/web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

and now when I execute `pub get` I get the following error:

```
Error on line 15, column 3 of ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auth0_lock-0.1.0/pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer "dart_to_js_script_rewriter": package "dart_to_js_script_rewriter" is not a dependency.
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

since I'm new to dart and not entirely sure what I'm doing.. I have no idea how to fix this :)

any ideas ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same error when adding `auth0_lock: ^0.1.0` to my dependencies and running `pub get`. The error message says that "dart_to_js_script_rewriter" is not a dependency in the pubspec.yaml of the auth0_lock package. It looks like it's added under `dev_dependecies` if you look [here](https://github.com/andresaraujo/auth0_lock.dart/blob/master/pubspec.yaml). [Dev dependencies](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#dev-dependencies) of any dependent packages are ignored. Pub only gets *your* package’s dev dependencies.

So I think this is a problem in their package.

So, what I did was I went to https://github.com/andresaraujo/auth0_lock.dart and cloned the package, added it into my own project root in a directory called `auth0_lock`. And then, in my pubspec.yaml i put:

```
auth0_lock:
    path: auth0_lock
```

After that I can import it using

```
import 'package:auth0_lock/auth0_lock.dart';
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1259. This is a limitation of `pub`. It was discussed to support `dev_transformers` for transformers to only run for a package when the package itself is built, not when it is built as a dependency of another package. The transformer is only used in `auth0_lock` for examples and irrelevant when used as a dependency.